# filter scope dont return the right result

Tags: laravel-5, filter, eloquent

hey i right this  code to filter and search a table base on two list of data 
so i wright in my controller this code

```
  $films = Film::filter()->get();
```

and in my model this:

```
 public function scopeFilter($query)
    {
        $directors = request('director')[0];
        $genres=request('genre')[0];
        if (isset($directors) && $directors != []) {
            foreach ($directors as $director) {
                $query->orwhere('director', $director);
            }
            if( isset($genres) && $genres!=[] ){
                    $query->where(function ($query) use ($genres){
                        foreach ($genres as $genre) {
                            $query->orwhere('genre', $genre);
                        }
                    });
            }
        }else{
            if( isset($genres) && $genres!=[] ){
                foreach ($genres as $genre) {
                    $query->orwhere('genre', $genre);
                }
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

in the end between two variable use of or instead of and 
does anyone can fix this 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving an error? When you say it isn't working, what specifically isn't working? Is it the data that it is returning is incorrect?

Also, what does the contents of the `$directors` and `$genres` arrays look like? Are they simply array's filled with ID's? If yes, you could try doing `whereIn` clauses instead of having to iterate through all items:

```
public function scopeFilter($query)
{
    $directors = request('director')[0];
    $genres=request('genre')[0];

    // Assuming they look like this:
    // $directors = [1,2,3];
    // $genres = [4,5,6];

    if (isset($directors) && count($directors)) {
        $query->whereIn('director', $directors);
    }
    else if(isset($genres) && count($genres)) {
        $query->whereIn('genre', $genres);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding not like this its more similar to e commerce website that you can choose  some brands like ['apple','samsong',...] and after that of between of them choose some other options like ['red,'yellow',...] and then filters the products with this filters